# How to insert file object at specific index in an empty array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIdof.png)I need to insert a file object at specific index like:1,5,6 in an empty array using angularJs. I want result something like given in the following attached image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `[n]` notation.

```js
const myArray = []

myArray[1] = 'something'
myArray[5] = 'inserted'
myArray[6] = 'in array'

console.log('myArray ', myArray)
```

Although I would recommend using javascript object if you need to work with custom property names.

Then you would do something like this:

```
const myObject = {}
myObject[1] = 'first file'
myObject[5] = 'second file'
myObject[6] = 'third file'
```

and you can always iterate through that object like this:

```
Object.keys(myObject).forEach(propertyName => console.log('property name ', propertyName, ' property value ', myObject[propertyName]));
```

Comment: It is working for only first insertion and not after that

Comment: What do you mean?